# Fortify 360 fortifyclient downloadFPR returning Access Denied

Tags: fortify

I'm trying to download my Fortify 360 fpr file through command line so I can automate a process with the following command:

```
fortifyclient -url [url] -authtoken [token] downloadFPR -file "C:\path\to\local\Fortify.fpr" -projectID [projectID]
```

The problem is that I am getting the following message when I try this:

```
Access Denied.  Please ensure the requested project exists and the supplied user has appropriate permissions.
```

I have all permissions needed to upload/download the fpr through the web UI and I've been able to successfully upload the fpr from command line, it's just downloading it that I'm having a problem with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out my issue was related to my token.  I had generated my token using AnalysisUploadToken for my gettoken argument and that only allows uploading.  I had to create another token using AnalysisDownloadToken in order to upload it.